# How do I find the exact solution to the boundary value problem $y'' = 4y' + y + 2 − 8x − x^ {2}$ , $y(0) = 0$ and $ y(4) = 16$?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am approaching this question by trying to guess the general solution to the boundary value problem. However I haven't come up with one. Can someone explain how to solve this question please?

Comment: @SimonS I understand the procedure. However I am not sure how to find the general solutions for the homogeneous and in-homogeneous equations. Can you explain that please?

Comment: You might want to go back to some basics, starting here:
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-9-solving-second-order-linear-odes-with-constant-coefficients/

Comment: @Jnyeboah93 I don't know if you've used Laplace Transforms before, but I thought it would be instructive to see a solution using this well-known methodology.  It is fast and reliable.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @SimonS Thanks I understand that procedure. Is there a different procedure to find the solution to the BVP y′′(x)=−xy′(x)+y(x)−1, y(0)=1, y(4)=9, where the coefficient of y'(x) is not a constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will go through the details if you like, but the general solution is achieved by finding the complementary and particular solution, then adding the two together. You find the complementary solution by solving
\begin{equation*}
y''-4y'-y=0.
\end{equation*}
Assume solution it proportional to $e^{\lambda x}$ and substitute this in for $y.$ Find the derivatives and factor out $e^{\lambda x}.$ This will leave you with a polynomial. Find a solution for this.

For the particular solution, it will be of the form
\begin{equation*}
y_p=c_1+c_2x+c_3x^2
\end{equation*}
where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are unknown constants. Find $y'_p$ and $y''_p$ and substitute this into the differential equation. To find the constants, you equate the coefficients of $1,x$ and $x^2$. Does that help?

Comment: I do not understand how I am supposed to solve $y′′−4y−y=0$. Can you explain that please? Also when I plug in $y_p$ into the homogeneous equation how do I find the constants?

Comment: I'll add it to my answer

Comment: I did mean -4y' and have changed it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @GeorgeS Thanks I understand. Is the procedure the same for this BVP $y''(x) = −xy'(x) + y(x) − 1$, $y(0) = 1$, $y(4) = 9$, where the coefficient of y'(x) is not a constant?

Comment: I would have thought so. I will have a look at it and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be instructive to show the use of Laplace Transforms to solve a boundary value problem.

Recall that

$$\mathscr{L}\{y'\}(s) = sY(s) -y(0)$$

and

$$\mathscr{L}\{y''\}(s) = s^2Y(s) -sy(0)-y'(0)$$

Although $y'(0)$ is not specified in the boundary value problem, we will find a solution in terms of $y'(0)$ as an unknown, and find the full solution be enforcing $y(4)=16$.

We will also use

$$\mathscr{L}\{x\}(s) =\frac{1}{s^2} $$

and

$$\mathscr{L}\{x^2\}(s) =\frac{2}{s^3} $$

Then, we have

$$Y(s)=\frac{\frac{2}{s}-\frac{8}{s^2}-\frac{2}{s^3}+y'(0)}{s^2-4s-1}=\frac{2}{s^3}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} y'(0)\left(\frac{1}{s-2-\sqrt{5}}-\frac{1}{s-2+\sqrt{5}}\right)$$

whereupon inversion reveals that

$$y(x)=x^2+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{10}y'(0)\left(e^{(2+\sqrt{5})x}-e^{(2-\sqrt{5})x}\right)$$

Now, enforcing $y(4)=16$ gives $y'(0)=0$ and thus the full solution becomes

$$y(x) = x^2$$